# Prove that the eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator form a basis

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

While I was reading the book [**Quantum Mechanics The Theoretical Minimum**](https://archive.org/details/QuaMecTheTheMin), the author said that if a vector space is $N$ dimensional, an orthonormal basis of $N$ vectors can be constructed from eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator.
How can we prove this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's stick with finite-dimensional spaces. In infinite dimensions, you might deal with linear *unbounded* operators, and need to take much more care on how you define spectrum and what you mean with "eigenvalues". See *e.g.* [MSE1557878](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557878/173147).
I'll provide a brief overview of some standard arguments. For more detailed/technical treatments, you can see any standard linear algebra resource.

---

***Diagonalisable —*** Let $A$ be any *diagonalisable* matrix in a finite-dimensional vector space. A common definition of "diagonalisable" is similarity with a diagonal matrix. That is, $A$ is diagonalisable if $A=PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible (squared) $P$ and diagonal $D$. The eigenvectors of $A$ are then the columns of $P$. This is equivalent to saying that there is a basis of eigenvector for $A$. You can either take this as a *definition* of diagonalisability, or if you instead use the definition above, just observe that $P$ is invertible *iff* its columns are linearly independent, which in turn is equivalent to them forming a basis for the space.

Note that this doesn't say anything about the basis of eigenvectors needing to be orthogonal. Consider for example
$$A\equiv \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\qquad
B\equiv \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $A$ is diagonalisable, with eigenvectors $(1,0)^T$ and $(1,1)^T$. On the other hand, $B$ is *not* diagonalisable, and its only eigenvector is $(1,0)^T$.

***Normal —*** If $A$ is also *normal*, meaning $AA^\dagger=A^\dagger A$, then it is (1) always diagonalisable, and (2) always admits a basis of *orthonormal* eigenvectors. For example, $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ is normal (and not Hermitian), with (orthogonal) eigenvectors $(1,\pm i)^T$, and eigenvalues $1\pm i$.
As an additional interesting tidbit, any matrix $A$ can be decomposed uniquely as $A=A_1+iA_2$ with $A_1,A_2$ Hermitians, and then $A$ is normal *iff* $[A_1,A_2]=0$.
In the above example, you'd get $A=I + iY$ with $Y$ Pauli matrix, thus $A_1=I$, $A_2=Y$, and clearly $[I,Y]=0$.

***Hermitian —*** A normal matrix $A$ is *Hermitian* iff it has real eigenvalues. If $A$ is normal and has real eigenvalues it is straightforward to verify that $A^\dagger=A$. If on the other hand $A=A^\dagger$, then clearly $AA^\dagger=A^\dagger A$, thus $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, but if $v$ is an eigenvector then $\langle v,Av\rangle=\lambda$ with $\lambda$ associated eigenvalue, and if $A$ is Hermitian then $\langle v,Av\rangle\in\mathbb{R}$. See also [MSE913093](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913093/173147).

---

There's many possible paths to prove these things. One possibility is to start from Hermitian matrices. You show that if $A$ is Hermitian then $\|Av\|$ has a maximum in the compact set of unit vectors. That's because, roughly speaking, you have for Hermitian matrices that $\delta \|A v\|^2=2 \langle \delta v ,A v\rangle$, and thus $\delta \|Av\|=0$ iff $\delta v\perp Av$ for all displacements $\delta v$ in the sphere. In other words, the max of $\|Av\|$ corresponds to $v$ such that $Av$ is orthogonal to all displacements $\delta v$ in the sphere, which by definition are orthogonal to $v$. In other words, you must have $Av=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. It is then not hard to see you must have $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. You then iterate the argument considering the action of $A$ on the subspace orthogonal to $v$.
There's many other possible approaches, for example relying instead on the fundamental theorem of algebra. See *e.g.* the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Once you show the result for Hermitian matrices, you easily get it for general normal matrices, because as mentioned above $A$ is normal iff its Hermitian and skew-Hermitian components commute: $A=A_1+iA_2$ with $A_1,A_2$ Hermitian and $[A_1,A_2]=0$. But this means that there is a basis of common eigenvectors for $A_1$ and $A_2$ ([MSE1227031](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1227031/173147)), that is, a basis of eigenvectors $v_k$ such that
$$Av_k=A_1 v_k + i A_2 v_k = (\lambda^{(1)}_k + i \lambda^{(2)}_k)v_k$$
for $\lambda_k^{(i)}\in\mathbb{R}$. You thus get an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $A$, with generally complex eigenvalues.

Comment: What a complete and thorough and patient answer.